# Division width issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ew4Y3/2/).

**Scenario -** Here The individual divisions one,two,three are dynamic. The number of individual blocks might increase.

I want to find the total width of the those 4 blocks. And I want to assign that width to the above Grey block.

So Whenever new blocks are added, The above grey block's width should be equal to the total width of the blocks.

```
<div class="head">
<div class="top"></div>

<div class="body">
    <div class="body-inner">
        <div class="w one"></div>
        <div class="w two"></div>
        <div class="w three"></div>
        <div class="w four"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am just getting whole block width as wel as individual width.But how do i get the width of the 4 blocks? and it is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not move your top div into the body-inner div, then just set:

```
.body-inner
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ew4Y3/7/)** (no JS required)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate width of each block and assign that width to `.top`.

I've made here function `refreshWidthCalculation()`, that you need to call everytime if you are adding new `<div class="w"></div>`

Here is updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew4Y3/4/)

```
var w=0;
$('document').ready(function() {
    refreshWidthCalculation();
});
function refreshWidthCalculation(){
  w=0; 
  $(".w").each(function(){
      w+=$(this).width();
  });
  $(".top").width(w);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But the grey box width is not exactly equal to the below overall width.

Comment: because in css you didn't mentioned `width` of `.five`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code inside ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = 0;
$('.w').each(function () {
    x += $(this).width();
});
alert(x);

var y = $('.body').width();
alert(y);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew4Y3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J4xUZ/)

```
    var onew=$('.one').width();
    var twow=$('.two').width();
    var threew=$('.three').width();
    var fourw =$('.four').width();
    $('.body-inner').width(  onew + twow + threew + fourw );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's

[outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) - Returns the width of the element, along with left and right padding, border, and optionally margin, in pixels.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var x = 0;

    $('.w').each(function () {
        x += $(this).outerWidth() + 10;
    });


    //10 because first-child does not have margin left and last-child does not have margin right
    x -= 10;

    $(".top").css("width", x + "px");

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew4Y3/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a *.container*, *clearfix* and *inline-block*

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ew4Y3/10/

**PS** basically the same as Danield's answer

Answer (score 0):

use that

```
display: inline-block;
```